# Can `Array.find` use a default value if the callback function doesn't return anything truthy?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using `Array.find` in one of my JavaScript handlers, and discovered that sometimes there is no truthy test, and so the property gets set to `undefined`. I worked around it like this:

```
const previous = this.value;
this.value = this.values.find((value) => value.Id === event.detail.valueId);
if (!this.value) {
    this.value = previous;
}
```

Is there any way to give a default value to the `find` method so that if nothing is found it uses that as a fallback?

Comment: Just the same as anything else that can use a fallback `arr.find() || fallbackValue` or with newer syntax `arr.find() ?? fallbackValue`.

Comment: Depends on the contents of `this.value`. Are they all guaranteed to be objects? Then `.find(...) || previous` is fine. If they might have falsey values, then use multiple lines as you have but be specific about testing against undefined. `??` is specific for null and undefined only, but there's still a little room for a false positive if `null` is a legal value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `??` syntax to return a result if your left hand statement is null or undefined

```
this.value = this.values.find((value) => value.Id === event.detail.valueId) ?? true;
```

This is called the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) , and it's a more specific case of the previously common `||` because that one returns the right hand side value whenever something is "false", not only null or undefined (e.g. also when the LHS is 0 or false)

Comment: Om my, I was today years old wen I learned that `??` is more useful than `||` in most cases.

Comment: @somethinghere it’s much safer too

Comment: @DanielA.White Haven't really ran into issues using `||` but it's rather interesting and will definitely use it now.

Comment: @somethinghere You might if you try it with numbers. I've had problems when I had something like `minValue = config.min || 10` - consider the case for `config.min = 0`, then `minValue` would be erroneously set to `10` instead of only using the default if there is no config for that. Similar thing if you try to default a string, e.g., `description = config.description || "ADD TEXT"` or defaulting a boolean to `true`, e.g., you have `required = config.mandatory || true`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
const find_value = this.values.find((value) => value.Id === event.detail.valueId)
this.value = find_value ? find_value : previous
```